# Application running using os.exec doesn't load java libraries properly

Tags: java, go, minecraft

I would really appreciate if you helped me. I'm rewriting a simple Minecraft launcher from Java to Go. Everything is good, in exception of one thing.
I have a start function which executes using os.Exec this command:

```
java -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Djava.library.path="/minecraft/bin/natives/" -cp "/minecraft/bin/*" -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch --username user --session session --version 1.6.4 --gameDir "/minecraft" --assetsDir "/minecraft" --tweakClass cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
```

Everything is fine running this through bash or cmd, but when executed with Go function it returns the following:

```
Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
```

I think os.exec(Command) cannot properly interpet this part of command:

```
-cp "/minecraft/bin/*"
```

Maybe that's because I quoted string "/minecraft/bin/*" with strconv.Quote() function or because of asterisk. I really don't know what's heppening. Ah, btw, the command os.exec has run is correct, though (I read it in stdout with fmt for debugging purposes).

program:

```
func start(login string, session string, ram string) {
//start game

app := "java"
arg0 := "-Xincgc"
arg1 := "-Xmx" + ram + "M"
arg2 := "-Djava.library.path=" + strconv.Quote(filepath.FromSlash(client+"bin/natives/"))
arg3 := "-cp"
arg4 := strconv.Quote(filepath.FromSlash(client + "bin/*"))
arg5 := "-Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true"
arg6 := "-Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true"
arg7 := "net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch"
arg8 := "--username"
//arg9 is login
arg10 := "--session"
//arg11 is session
arg12 := "--version 1.6.4"
arg13 := "--gameDir"
arg14 := strconv.Quote(filepath.FromSlash(client))
arg15 := "--assetsDir"
arg16 := strconv.Quote(filepath.FromSlash(client + "assets"))
arg17 := "--tweakClass cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker"

cmd := exec.Command(app, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, login, arg10, session, arg12, arg13, arg14, arg15, arg16, arg17)
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()
fmt.Println(app, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, login, arg10, session, arg12, arg13, arg14, arg15, arg16, arg17)
}
```

Comment: Your `minecraft` directory is really under the root directory (`/`)? It isn't under your home directory?

Comment: OK, one second. No, the directory is on /home, of course.

Comment: You should keep the arguments separated: `arg12 := "--version 1.6.4"` becomes `arg12 := "--version"` and `arg13 := "1.6.4"`

Comment: Attached a code as well.

Comment: Oh, and tweakclass too.

Comment: And you should not quote the arguments. It's a shell thing.

Comment: Yes, it works! @topskip, big thanks for your help! I'm always doing stupid mistakes...

Comment: @topskip sorry, I wrote my answer before seing the edits and your comments. If you write an answer accepted by the OP, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @VonC Your answer looks fine (except that I am confused with the double quotes), so there is no need for another answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question "[Properly pass arguments to Go Exec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025343/6309)" mentions:

> `exec.Command(...)` adds double quotes to the parameters if there is spaces in them, so you only need to escape `\"` where you need them.

In your case, `-cp "/minecraft/bin/*"` would be passed to `exec.Command` as two separate parameters.

If you need quotes within one parameter, you could use a [string literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) to keep them (as commented in "[How do you add spaces to exec.command in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25633077/6309)").

But if, in your case, you need the `cp` (classpath) to be expended by the shell (as mentioned in "[double quotes escaping in golang exec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26473771/6309)"), then remove the quotes:

```
exec.Command(..., "-cp", `/minecraft/bin/*`, ...)
```